# Browser does not set cookie

Tags: node.js, http, express, cookies

In my NodeJS Express app (built with feathers); I'm trying to work with cookies with client-side `fetch` from client javascript. I have Express using the `cooke-parser` middleware.

I have tried setting the `credentials` header to `same-origin`, but that has stopped working (it worked fine yesterday, and a few times today... but I've been trying to build up the cookie to what I need and it just doesn't seem to reliably work).

This is my test express route:

```
app.post('/setjwt', (req, res, next) => {
 res.cookie('acokie', 'lol');
 res.status(200);
 res.send();
});
```

I'm using `fetch` in chrome dev tools console to test sending requests like so:

```
fetch('/setjwt', { method: 'POST', headers: { credentials: 'same-origin' } } );
```

These are the headers:
[image]

But there is no cookie listed in the Application tab nor available in `document.cookie`.

The reason I have this route is two fold:

1. Understand how cookies work and interop with Express.
2. Get rid of this hacky route altogether and get the headers/environment set up correctly so my feathers authentication service's Set-Cookie response header is respected by the browser.

The feathers client on the login page is set up with `fetch` as its rest implementation, and I can set

Answer (score 0):

`fetch('/setjwt', { method: 'POST', headers: { credentials: 'same-origin' } } );` won't work.

The credentials property [cannot be specified like that with fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/349#issuecomment-225699815). The correct code is:

```
fetch(
  '/setjwt',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: { whatever: 'somevalue' }
  });
```

---

As for setting it up so that the feathers authentication service would work,  again, it's not a normal header so [brushing up on the documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/rest.html#restbaseurl) hopefully might yield something useful, but I don't think the feathers-rest wrapper over fetch [supports passing non header options](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-rest/blob/master/src/client/base.js).